# Cardinal Arithmetic, Regular Cardinals, and Exponentiation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I cannot solve a simple cardinal exponentiation/regularity exercise.
Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal.  Why is the cardinal $\kappa^{\lt \kappa}=\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}\kappa^\alpha$ regular as well?
I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: Who gave you this exercise? Is there additional context to it? As stated, you can't prove this because it's not provable (i.e. consistently false).

Answer (score 4):

This is [consistently] false.

It is consistent that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega_1}$, which is singular. In this case take $\kappa=\aleph_1$ then $$\kappa^{<\kappa}=\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega_1}.$$

---

Of course, this is also consistently true, under $\sf GCH$ we have that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ for every regular cardinal.

Comment: For this we need kappa^lambda=kappa for each lambda<kappa;why this is so under GCH?

Comment: Because cardinal exponentiation quite trivializes understand GCH. You should sit to prove this yourself, it's not very hard. Start with the fact (which is true in general) that $\lambda^\lambda=2^\lambda$.